# How to read large pcap file in python

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

I have to build an application that read a min of 10GB sized pcap file. Scapy took almost an hour to read an 11GB file. Can anybody suggest a better way to do that??

This is the snip of the code

```
from scapy.all import *
import time

print("started reading")
start = time.time()

scapy_cap = PcapReader('large.pcapng')
for packet in scapy_cap:    
    pass

end = time.time()
print("read")
print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
```

I used the pyshark.FileCapture and the time is almost same.

I want the code to run on all platform.

**Thanks for any answers**